# Gnuplot reducing the y axis range

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following plot.
[image]

My y axis range is too high so I used commands like

```
       set yrange [70:90]
```

However I have many plots and I cannto set the range by numerical values. So I have used the followind commands

```
set yrange [ymin:ymax]
```

but it did not worked
 so I have used

```
set yrange [GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN:GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX]
```

but the y range is then completly different. Is there any other way to set the y range

Comment: You actually do have a data point at (0,0), so the automatic range does not come as a surprise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN` and etc... gets its value **after** the plot. To use the corresponding values you have to plot twice.

Sőt!

`GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN` and etc... gets value from the last **dataset/datafile** you have ploted :-/